# How to access session in OnAuthorizationCodeReceived

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, openid-connect

I am not sure ,but is it possible to access session variable in OnAuthorizationCodeReceived callback while getting access token from.

My requirement is like using DBConnection ,to store token in database . As Session["DBConnection "] is always null.

Using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Thanks

```
public void SignIn()
    {
        Session["DBConnection "] = GetConnectionObject();
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

In Startup.Auth.cs

```
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        // Upon successful sign in, get the access token & cache it using MSAL
        IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = await MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "User.Read" }, context.Code).ExecuteAsync();
        string token = authResult?.IdToken;
       
        if (token != null)
        {
        
        /* connection is always null*/
            var connection= HttpContext.Current.Session["DBConnection "]
            
            
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
            
        }
    }
```